# UIApplication shared object not giving scheduled notification

Tags: ios, swift

I have scheduled a notification in my app and create a actionable notification with snooze button. On snooze button handling I have created another notification and scheduled it. But when I start app and try to get that scheduled notification its saying 0 scheduled notification, and when I again start app after killing it. Its giving that notification.

What's wrong why isn't its giving me scheduled notification first time.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    if identifier == Constants.NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY_ACTION_RESUME {
    // do something
    } else if identifier == Constants.NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY_ACTION_SNOOZE {
    // extracting time from notification user info and scheduling another notification of same time
      let userInfo = notification.userInfo
      let newNotification = UILocalNotification()
      let timeInterval = userInfo!["timeInterval"] as! NSTimeInterval
      newNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeInterval)
      if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
        newNotification.alertTitle = Utilities.getLocalizedString("NotificationAlertTitle")
      } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
      }
      newNotification.alertBody = Utilities.getLocalizedString("NotificationAlertBody")
      newNotification.alertAction = Utilities.getLocalizedString("NotificationAlertAction")
      newNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
      newNotification.category = Constants.CATEGORY_NAME
      // use this to store previous time
      let date = NSDate()
      newNotification.userInfo = [Constants.NOTIFICATIONUSERINFO_TIMEINTERVAL : timeInterval, Constants.NOTIFICATIONUSERINFO_TAG : Constants.NOTIFICATION_TAG, Constants.NOTIFICATIONUSERINFO_SETTIME : date.timeIntervalSince1970]

      UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(newNotification)
    }
    completionHandler()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've used this method `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`. And this method cancels all of the scheduled notifications list. You can cancel a specific scheduled notification by using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(YourSpecificNotification)`. Do not call any `cancelLocalNotification` methods while creating a new local notification.

Comment: There is nothing like this in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications)